# remove point and transform value into column of data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to know how I can transform values into data.frame columns by removing a "." (in relation to the decimal) to obtain a new variable.

For example, transform:

```
pop <- structure(list(data = c(104.047, 105.254, 106.422, 107.79, 108.765, 
109.685)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

In:

```
pop <- structure(list(data = c(104047, 105254, 106422, 10779, 108765, 
                        109685)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thankful.

Comment: In case `pop$data * 1000` is not what you are looking for than maybe: `as.numeric(sub(".", "", as.character(pop$data), fixed = TRUE))`

Comment: Thank you @GKi, answered perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as.character` to convert it to a *character*, use `sub` to remove the `.` and cast it back to *numeric* with `as.numeric`.

```
pop$data <- as.numeric(sub(".", "", as.character(pop$data), fixed = TRUE))
pop
#    data
#1 104047
#2 105254
#3 106422
#4  10779
#5 108765
#6 109685
```

Comment: Thank you, answered perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply:

```r
df <- structure(list(data = c(104.047, 105.254, 106.422, 107.79, 108.765, 
                        109.685)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")


df$data_new <- df$data * 1000
```

Comment: Thanks @Moritz Schwarz !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
pop$data <- as.numeric(sub("\\.", "", as.character(pop$data)))
```